# chanigng color of rowx in table

Tags: php, css

hello i am working on the styling of table in PHP . I am stuck at only one point that ***i am not able to to change the colors of the rows of my table alternatively like odd rows should be displayed with white background and even with blue*** . i trie the followng css code but it didnot worked

```
tbody:nth-child(2n) { /* even rows */ 
  background-color:#eee;
}     
tbody:nth-child(2n+1) { /* odd rows */
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not because of your browser issue, please try this for css

```
table#tableid tr:nth-child(2n) { /* even rows */ 
  background-color:#eee;
}     
table#tableid tr:nth-child(2n+1) { /* odd rows */
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

OR

```
table#tableid tr:nth-child(even) { /* even rows */ 
  background-color:#eee;
}     
table#tableid tr:nth-child(odd) { /* odd rows */
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: `:nth-child(odd)`/`:nth-child(even)` would be slightly more clear, though to the same effect.

Comment: @user1371693. Try to add `table#tableid` or `#tableid` then

Answer (score 1):

i think jquery [:even](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) and [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector is the best option for cross browsers..

```
$('#selector:even').addClass('even_class');
$('#selector:odd').addClass('odd_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Write two classes to for the styles of odd and even rows. And add the class alternately like this.

```
.odd_row{
   background-color:grey;
}
.even_row{
   background-color:white;
}

And in php,
<?php
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{?>
      <tr class="<?php echp ($i%2==0)?'odd_row':'even_row';?>">
           <td>data1</td>
           <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using a variable to change which style is used. So when you start the block, you define `oddOrEven` as 0, then you echo a row, then you set `oddOrEven` to 1. Every time a row is echoed, it changes which class is used based on `oddOrEven`.